How to know what factors should we breaking the function into in finding limit?
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}x(\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x)$$
The solution to this problem is to factor $x$ into $-x-1+2x+1$ and then conjugate and the limit is $\frac{-1}{4}$.
My question is how do we know that $x$ is factored into $-x-1+2x+1$ ? Why don't we use $2x-x$?
This is what I got when I used $2x-x$.
$x\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+2x-x-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}\right)$
$x\left(\frac{x^{2}+2x-x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x}+\frac{4x^{2}-4x^{2}-4x}{2x+2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}\right)$
$\frac{2x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x}-\frac{2x^{2}}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}$
$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}$
$2-2=0$ which is the wrong answer.
P.S. The mistakes in my steps have been pointed out by user in the comment. Thank you for your help!

MathJax Tip: when using $$ to enclose maths expressions, you automatically get \displaystyle when rendering, making the tag redundant. If you want inline mathematics, enclose with $ instead. For example, writing $-x-1+2x+1$ would produce $-x-1+2x+1$, as opposed to $$-x-1+2x+1$$, which produces$$-x-1+2x+1$$

What will happen if we multiply both the numerator and denominator by $x$. Then the above limit will be of the form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ . Now, can't we apply L-Hospital's rule then ?

We have that by this choice
$$\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x=\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}-x-1-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+2x+1$$
and
$$\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}-x-1=\frac{x^{2}+2x-(x+1)^2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x+1}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x+1}$$
$$2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}-2x-1=\frac{4x^2+4x-(2x+1)^2}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+2x+1}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+2x+1}$$
which is a very clever choice to factor out $x$ terms from numerator which is not obtained by the other choice.

To figure out this way by inspection and completing the square we have

$x^{2}+2x+1 = (x+1)^2$
$4x^2+4x+1=(2x+1)^2$

with $(2x+1)-(x+1)=x$.

By the suggested (clever) method we obtain
$$x(\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x+1}+\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+2x+1}=$$
$$=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac 2x}+1+\frac1x}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+2+\frac1x}\to-\frac12+\frac14 =-\frac14$$
but with the other one
$$x(\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}+x)=x\left(\frac{x^{2}+2x-x^2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x}+\frac{4x^2-4x^2-4x}{2x+2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x}-\frac{4x^2}{2x+2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+\frac2x}+1}-\frac{4x}{2+2\sqrt{1+\frac1x}}$$
which is in the form $\infty-\infty$.

Hi! Thank you for your answer. The limit when I used $2x-x$ (0) is different from the limit I got when I used $(2x+1)-(x+1)$ ($\frac{-1}{4}$ which is the correct answer). May be I made a mistake calculating somewhere? $$x(\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+2x-x-2\sqrt{x^{2}+x})$$ $$x\left(\frac{x^{2}+2x-x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x}+\frac{4x^{2}-4x^{2}-4x}{2x+2\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}\right)$$ $$\frac{2x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}+x}+\frac{-2x^{2}}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}$$ $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}$$ $$2-2=0$$

Yes there is some mistake both in the first step and in the last.

We would have in the numerator $x^2+2x-x^2$ and similar for the second term. But it seems a typo.

Moreover in the last step, when divide $\sqrt{x^2+2x}$ by $x^2$ you don’t obtain what you have indicated. Indeed $$\sqrt{x^2+2x}=x\sqrt{1+2/x}$$

I also noticed a small typo in the answer, I fix it.

It would be nice if you can include your steps into the text editing your question with this addendum.
